# Question in a trigonometric equation.

Tags: trigonometry

I tried it a lot but am not able to get this.Pls help in how should I think when solving this type of question and which side is better to *try to simplify first* (LHS or RHS).Please share the solution in that way.

$$
\frac{1-\sin A}{1+\sin A} = 1 + 2 \tan A \left(\tan A - \sec A \right)
$$

One of the ways I tried but am not understand that how to simplify it in such a way that you get the RHS?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Personally, for me, the first step is to change the RHS so that it is only using the sine and cosine functions.  The next step is to mulitply both sides by $(1 + \sin A)$, to eliminate the LHS denominator.

Comment: How to simplify it?

Comment: What Ramnanujan's comment is suggesting is that your question, *as stated* is gibberish.  My guess is that what you *intended* to ask is which side should you try to simplify first.

Comment: Yes but am not able to get the answer by both sides I tried

Comment: I want to know how should we think in this situation and how to solve it?

Comment: Okay, please implement the suggestions in my first comment, and then edit your query to **show your work**.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear with my question.

Comment: It will be easy to start with RHS.

Comment: And try to simplify all to sin function.

Comment: After that I am not getting

Comment: I was about to comment but no point now as I see couple of people already decided to do your homework for you. Good luck!

Comment: Also, please check out https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation.

Comment: @MathLover you can't shout fire in a crowded theater.

Comment: @user2661923 yes I realize that :) btw I end up doing that many times too and then I think may be I should have let the person think through it a bit more.

Comment: I will try to question in that approach next time.

Comment: What you’re saying is right sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the LHS we have $$\frac{1-\sin(A)}{1+\sin(A)}$$
$$=\frac{1-\sin(A)}{1+\sin(A)}\cdot\frac{1-\sin(A)}{1-\sin(A)}=\frac{1-2\sin(A)+\sin^2(A)}{1-\sin^2(A)}$$
$$=\frac{\cos^2(A)-2\sin(A)+2\sin^2(A)}{\cos^2(A)}$$

using the identity $\sin^2(A)+\cos^2(A)=1$. Can you end it now?

Comment: Yes thank you sir

Comment: What strategy did you think of before solving it?

Comment: You’re welcome! First to rationalise the denominator, then since the denominator simplifies to $\cos^2(x)$ and we have a $1$ on the RHS, I applied the identity to get the  $\cos^2(x)$ in the numerator so we could cancel (which also introduced another $2$ in the numerator).

Answer (score 0):

You have $LHS$ in terms of sine. So it's better to prove that $RHS = LHS$ as $\tan$ and $\sec$ can be converted into terms of $\cos$ and $ \sin$.
$\begin{align}1+2\tan A(\tan A - \sec A) &= 1+2\dfrac{\sin A(\sin A- 1)}{\cos^2A}  \\&=  \dfrac{\cos^2A+2\sin A(\sin A- 1)}{\cos^2A} \\&=\dfrac{(\cos^2A+\sin^2A)+\sin^2A-2\sin A}{1-\sin^2A}
\\&=\dfrac{(1-\sin A)^2}{1-\sin^2A} = \color{blue}{\dfrac{1-\sin A}{1+\sin A}}\end{align}$

(Provided $A \ne (2n+1)\frac\pi2, n\in \Bbb Z$)

Comment: What strategy did you think of before solving it?

Comment: First of all $\tan$ and $\sec$ in product provides $\cos^2 A$ in the denominator. Which can be written as $1-\sin^2A = (1-\sin A)(1+\sin A).$ This indicated, I need $(1-\sin A)^2$ in the numerator so as to get the desired result.